# How to solve this language downloading issue?

Tags: installation, downloads, language-support

I have a problem when I try to download another language by the system setting menu, I have this error message :

```
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox-locale-fr_12.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found
```

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on an Acer C710 running Chrome OS

Comment: Do you run ChromeOS or Ubuntu on the Laptop?

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade your hole system, or at least firefox to a recent(23) version.

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```